# Irish passport holder travelling from Australia to Spain then Ireland. Does my spouse (Indonesian) require Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, ireland, indonesia

Quick question which I am find it difficult to find the correct answer. 
I am travelling to Spain from Australia on an Irish passport & will stay in Spain for 1 week then fly to Dublin. 
My Indonesian spouse is travelling with me (Indonesian passport) with a valid Irish visa; does my spouse require a Schengen visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, she does, but she should apply as the spouse of an EU citizen, so the visa should be free of charge and granted "on the basis of an accelerated procedure."

See http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm.

Comment: Note that she does not have to fill the most complicated fields of the form, either. The proof of the family relationship *replaces* finances, etc.